# C# get information about current active window

Tags: c#, process, window

I have an application which i want to run in the background. I want to get the executable name, for an example IExplorer.exe. I have played around with the following code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

public static void Main()
{
    int chars = 256;
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(chars);
    while (true)
    {
        // Obtain the handle of the active window.
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        // Update the controls.
        if (GetWindowText(handle, buff, chars) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(buff.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(handle.ToString());
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

That only gets me the Window title, and the handle ID. I want to get the executable name (and maybe more information).

How do i achieve that?

Comment: Look at the last answer of this question on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268302/get-the-titles-of-all-open-windows/31517889#31517889

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want "[GetWindowModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633517(VS.85).aspx)()" instead of GetWindowText
You pass in the hwnd, so you'll still need the call to GetForegroundWindow()

Comment: Ca I use an event to get Screen Title, i.e when the user changes focus of screen it should trigger@