# get the titles of all open windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I retrieve the titles of all open windows (including windows such as tabs in Internet Explorer)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Something like this:

```C#
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: in this way he would only get the main window of each process, he asked for all open windows in the system.

Comment: He says: "more like the names of all open apps".

Comment: Davide piras is right, i need all open windows. like tabs in Intrarnt exploer. Any way? Thanks again!

Comment: A list of all open windows in the system would be huge. It should be limited to top-level windows or desktop windows. In the case of Internet Explorer, many applications create children in the manner that IE does. If you think about it, it is unlikely that the only children that would apply is IE children (tabs) so the question is somewhat unclear. Top-level windows of processes versus IE tabs are totally different in the answer.

Comment: This gives me "hidden" windows/apps as well. Like Edge, Calculator, Microsoft Store, Settings, etc. How could I filter those?

Comment: It's worth noting that this does not give Explorer windows (your regular Windows file browser) nor Opera windows, at least right now that I try it (Win 7, .NET 4.5).

Answer (score 53):

Here’s some code you can use to get a list of all the open windows. Actually, you get a dictionary where each item is a KeyValuePair where the key is the handle (hWnd) of the window and the value is its title. It also finds pop-up windows, such as those created by `MessageBox.Show`.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using HWND = System.IntPtr;

/// <summary>Contains functionality to get all the open windows.</summary>
public static class OpenWindowGetter
{
  /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
  /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
  public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
  {
    HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
    Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

    EnumWindows(delegate(HWND hWnd, int lParam)
    {
      if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
      if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

      int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
      if (length == 0) return true;

      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
      GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

      windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
      return true;

    }, 0);

    return windows;
  }

  private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
}
```

And here’s some code that uses it:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
{
  IntPtr handle = window.Key;
  string title = window.Value;

  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", handle, title);
}
```

Credit: http://www.tcx.be/blog/2006/list-open-windows/

Comment: Tried to use this code, had to change the first line to `using HWND = System.IntPtr;` instead

Comment: It also finds pop-up windows, such as those created by MessageBox.Show("Some message", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

Comment: This works like a charm! One quick question: How can we read text from a MessageBox? Like if I wanted to log error message shown in MessageBox. Thank you!

Comment: I had a processs that opened multiple windows. This worked better for me than the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the previous answer that give me some errors, finaly I use this code with `GetOpenedWindows` function:

```
public class InfoWindow
{
            public IntPtr Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            public FileInfo File = new FileInfo( Application.ExecutablePath );
            public string Title = Application.ProductName;
            public override string ToString() {
                return  File.Name + "\t>\t" + Title;
            }
 }//CLASS

/// <summary>Contains functionality to get info on the open windows.</summary>
public static class RuningWindows
{   
            internal static event EventHandler WindowActivatedChanged;    
            internal static Timer TimerWatcher = new Timer();    
            internal static InfoWindow WindowActive = new InfoWindow();       
            internal static void DoStartWatcher() {
                TimerWatcher.Interval = 500;
                TimerWatcher.Tick += TimerWatcher_Tick;
                TimerWatcher.Start();    
            }                    

            /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
            /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
            public static IDictionary<IntPtr , InfoWindow> GetOpenedWindows()
            {
                IntPtr shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
                Dictionary<IntPtr , InfoWindow> windows = new Dictionary<IntPtr , InfoWindow>();

                EnumWindows( new EnumWindowsProc( delegate( IntPtr hWnd , int lParam ) {
                    if ( hWnd == shellWindow ) return true;
                    if ( !IsWindowVisible( hWnd ) ) return true;    
                    int length = GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
                    if ( length == 0 ) return true;    
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( length );
                    GetWindowText( hWnd , builder , length + 1 );    
                    var info = new InfoWindow();
                    info.Handle = hWnd;
                    info.File = new FileInfo( GetProcessPath( hWnd ) );
                    info.Title = builder.ToString();    
                    windows[hWnd] = info;
                    return true;    
                } ) , 0 );    
                return windows;
            }

            private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc( IntPtr hWnd , int lParam );  

            public static string GetProcessPath( IntPtr hwnd )
            {
                uint pid = 0;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwnd , out pid );
                if ( hwnd != IntPtr.Zero ) {
                    if ( pid != 0 ) {
                        var process = Process.GetProcessById( (int) pid );
                        if ( process != null ) {
                            return process.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }    

            [DllImport( "USER32.DLL" )]
            private static extern bool EnumWindows( EnumWindowsProc enumFunc , int lParam );

            [DllImport( "USER32.DLL" )]
            private static extern int GetWindowText( IntPtr hWnd , StringBuilder lpString , int nMaxCount );

            [DllImport( "USER32.DLL" )]
            private static extern int GetWindowTextLength( IntPtr hWnd );

            [DllImport( "USER32.DLL" )]
            private static extern bool IsWindowVisible( IntPtr hWnd );

            [DllImport( "USER32.DLL" )]
            private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

            [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
            private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

            //WARN: Only for "Any CPU":
            [DllImport( "user32.dll" , CharSet = CharSet.Auto , SetLastError = true )]
            private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId( IntPtr handle , out uint processId );    


            static void TimerWatcher_Tick( object sender , EventArgs e )
            {
                var windowActive = new InfoWindow();
                windowActive.Handle = GetForegroundWindow();
                string path = GetProcessPath( windowActive.Handle );
                if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( path ) ) return;
                windowActive.File = new FileInfo( path );
                int length = GetWindowTextLength( windowActive.Handle );
                if ( length == 0 ) return;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( length );
                GetWindowText( windowActive.Handle , builder , length + 1 );
                windowActive.Title = builder.ToString();
                if ( windowActive.ToString() != WindowActive.ToString() ) {
                    //fire:
                    WindowActive = windowActive;
                    if ( WindowActivatedChanged != null ) WindowActivatedChanged( sender , e );
                    Console.WriteLine( "Window: " + WindowActive.ToString() );
                }
            }

}//CLASS
```

Warning: You can only compil/debug under "Any CPU" to access to 32bits Apps...

Comment: `GetProcessPath` will leak memory. The line `var process = Process.GetProcessById( (int) pid );` needs to be wrapped in a using statement.

Answer (score 3):

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows

There is an example of using user.dll's EnumWindow in C# to list all open windows.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the **EnumWindow** API.

there are plenty of examples on how to use it from C#, I found something here:

[Get Application's Window Handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820909/get-applications-window-handles)

[Issue with EnumWindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970184/issue-with-enumwindows)

Comment: Cant understand it i afirde. can you give me an exmple, plesae?

Comment: Link-only answers are not answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hera's the function UpdateWindowsList_WindowMenu() that you must call after any operations are performed on Tabs.Here windowToolStripMenuItem is the menu item added to Window Menu to menu strip.

```
public void UpdateWindowsList_WindowMenu()  
{  
    //get all tab pages from tabControl1  
    TabControl.TabPageCollection tabcoll = tabControl1.TabPages;  

    //get  windowToolStripMenuItem drop down menu items count  
    int n = windowToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count;  

    //remove all menu items from of windowToolStripMenuItem  
    for (int i = n - 1; i >=2; i--)  
    {  
        windowToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveAt(i);  
    }  

    //read each tabpage from tabcoll and add each tabpage text to windowToolStripMenuItem  
    foreach (TabPage tabpage in tabcoll)  
    {  
        //create Toolstripmenuitem  
        ToolStripMenuItem menuitem = new ToolStripMenuItem();  
        String s = tabpage.Text;  
        menuitem.Text = s;  

        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabpage)  
        {  
            menuitem.Checked = true;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            menuitem.Checked = false;  
        }  

        //add menuitem to windowToolStripMenuItem  
        windowToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(menuitem);  

        //add click events to each added menuitem  
        menuitem.Click += new System.EventHandler(WindowListEvent_Click);  
    }  
}  

private void WindowListEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    //casting ToolStripMenuItem to ToolStripItem  
    ToolStripItem toolstripitem = (ToolStripItem)sender;  

    //create collection of tabs of tabContro1  
    //check every tab text is equal to clicked menuitem then select the tab  
    TabControl.TabPageCollection tabcoll = tabControl1.TabPages;  
    foreach (TabPage tb in tabcoll)  
    {  
        if (toolstripitem.Text == tb.Text)  
        {  
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tb;  
            //call UpdateWindowsList_WindowMenu() to perform changes on menuitems  
            UpdateWindowsList_WindowMenu();  
        }  
    }  
}
```