# c# Get process window titles

Tags: c#, arrays, window, mainwindow

```
    proc.MainWindowTitle.Contains("e")
```

How does one get the window titles of all the current windows containing "e" open instead of just the Main Window using the "MainWindowTitle" and store them into a string array?

**EDIT:**

```
     string[] toClose = {proc.MainWindowTitle};
                for (int i = 0; i < toClose.Length; i++)
                {
                    string s = toClose[i];
                    int hwnd = 0;

                    hwnd = FindWindow(null, s);

                    //send WM_CLOSE system message
                    if (hwnd != 0)
                        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Please read this related question (and the accepted answer). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268302/get-the-names-of-all-open-windows-not-process-name . I think that will help you.

Comment: If you mean to retrieve all the windows owned by that process, you need to look into [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx), and call a [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) on them with the WM_GETTEXT Msg.

Answer (score 5):

**Code snippet**

```
string[] result = new string[50];
int count = 0;
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(var process in processes)
{
    if (process.MainWindowTitle
               .IndexOf("e", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) > -1)
    {
        result[count] = process.MainWindowTitle;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Please review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268302/get-the-names-of-all-open-windows-not-process-name) (and the accepted answer) that guides my answer.

**Edit:**

If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve de list of processes main window titles.

Analysing your code below, the `toClose` variable always store one title: the `proc.MainWindowTitle` value.

```
string[] toClose = { proc.MainWindowTitle };
```

You must retrieve each window title using the `foreach` statement of my original answer. Then, you must use the `result` variable in the proposed solution instead of `toClose` variable on your piece of code.

Comment: edited OP with the current code which doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 5):

```
public static class MyEnumWindows
{
    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr windowHandle, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndStart, EnumWindowsProc callback, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out IntPtr lpdwResult);

    private static List<string> windowTitles = new List<string>();

    public static List<string> GetWindowTitles(bool includeChildren)
    {
        EnumWindows(MyEnumWindows.EnumWindowsCallback, includeChildren ? (IntPtr)1 : IntPtr.Zero);
        return MyEnumWindows.windowTitles;
    }

    private static bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr testWindowHandle, IntPtr includeChildren)
    {
        string title = MyEnumWindows.GetWindowTitle(testWindowHandle);
        if (MyEnumWindows.TitleMatches(title))
        {
            MyEnumWindows.windowTitles.Add(title);
        }
        if (includeChildren.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) == false)
        {
            MyEnumWindows.EnumChildWindows(testWindowHandle, MyEnumWindows.EnumWindowsCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        uint SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
        uint WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;
        int MAX_STRING_SIZE = 32768;
        IntPtr result;
        string title = string.Empty;
        IntPtr memoryHandle = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(MAX_STRING_SIZE);
        Marshal.Copy(title.ToCharArray(), 0, memoryHandle, title.Length);
        MyEnumWindows.SendMessageTimeout(windowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)MAX_STRING_SIZE, memoryHandle, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, (uint)1000, out result);
        title = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(memoryHandle);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(memoryHandle);
        return title;
    }

    private static bool TitleMatches(string title)
    {
        bool match = title.Contains("e");
        return match;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to iterate through the process list (can be made with

`Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();` )

with `foreach( Process in processlist )`

and write the `Process.MainWindowTitle` to the array. 
Try that :)

Comment: Tried this but it only returns one at a time not all

Comment: How are you adding it to the array?

Comment: edited OP thats how I'm doing it, but it only gets one window at a time @MaxMarchuk

Comment: Make sure you are addding the end of the array and not overwriting the previous processes. That may be the problem?

Comment: When you are iterating through the processlist in the ` foreach ` loop, are you adding the ` Process.MainWindowTitle ` to `array[array.count+1] ` ? adding it to array[array.count+1] will add it to the end of the array instead of overwriting what is already in it

Comment: Sorry this might sound stupid but how do I go about adding 1 each time to the array?

Comment: No Problem.
So you will want to delcare the array with 

`  string[] ProcessArray = new string[*Whatever size you want*]; ` 

and then insert the titles into that array with 

` ProcessArray[ProcessArray.Count+1] = Process.MainWindowTitle; `

Try that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34254/discussion-between-maxmarchuk-and-first-second)