# How to get names of all open windows (by a specific process) in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, window

I am currently search a way to get the titles/names of all open windows (from a specific process if possible) in c#. So a process can have multiple windows an I just found the Process.MainWindowTitle command, but I want the names of all the windows that run under this process, not just the MainWindowTitle. Is there a command/a way to get all window titles in a list/array? I searched through the internet but couldn't find anything that worked or I understand. It would be awesome if somebody has a way to do it and could explain it to me.

Thanks Akira

Edit: I found this link (http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/08/list-desktop-windows-in-c/) but I couldn't get it working and I don't understand what's going on there. So if anybody understand this...or if not just get it working to print out all titels in the console. I would be so thankful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;  

//will only get process with main window title property that is not empty

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
var processTitle = processlist.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.MainWindowTitle)).Select(c => c.MainWindowTitle).ToList();
```

`.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.MainWindowTitle)` is the part where you only select the main window title who is not an empty `string`. Then the `Select(c => c.MainWindowTitle)` only gets the `MainWindowTitle property` of each `Process`. `ToList` list all the values that match the `Where` condition to a `List<string>` because the `property` of `MainWindowTitle` is `string`

updated answer, almost still the same.

```
string processname = ""; //the process you want to capture
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
var processTitle = processlist.Where(c => c.ProcessName == processname).ToList();
```

still same explanation, now you supply on which process (`c.ProcessName == processname` will now only retrieve the specific process name you supplied.) you want to capture and you can now debug/capture the details you need.

or refer to this explanation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890354/2122217

Comment: I updated my question. Now it's clearer what I want.

Comment: That's not what I want because there are just the MainWindowTitles included and not every window's title.

Comment: @AkiraK. updated my answer, from what i understand you will supply the process name?