# Get the MainWindowTitle from a service

Tags: c#, service, process, windows-services, processlist

I need to get the Main Window title of the processes that are running in my desktop.

I have the following code:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    Response.Write(p.Id + " " + p.ProcessName + "_" + p.MainWindowTitle);
}
```

The problem is that if I run this code as a `*.exe` file, I can obtain all the data correctly, but If I run it as a service installed on my desktop, I only get the `ID` and the `ProcessName`, but the `MainWindowTitle` has `""` value.

Can someone help me? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Windows services cannot interact with the desktop. So I'm not surprised.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291367/getting-window-titles-from-a-windows-service

Comment: I did not find the duplicate option in "flag", seems I did not refresh the page...