# How to Get Running Application with C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, service

I've build a Windows service with C# which get all running applications on my computer (Notepad,...). I've tryed this following code but it doesn't work :

Thank you all for your help!

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Info.txt"))
{
  foreach(Process p in processes)
  {
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
    {
      tw.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what (and in what way) is not working?

Comment: Thank you for replying! It shows nothing. I think, may be the Windows Service can't interact with "MainWindowTitle". Because i've tryed this code with Windows form and it works.

Comment: [Getting window titles from a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294244/7444103). [ServiceController.GetServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why you are checking `MainWindowTitle` on your code. You have to know `MainWindowTitle` has value just for those processes which they have GUI like notepad or skype or ...

To identify all the process name it's better to check **`ProcessName`** property to get the process name.

So I recommend you to change your code like this:

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Info.txt"))
{
    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ProcessName))
        {
            var processTitle= !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle) ? p.MainWindowTitle: "N/A";
            tw.WriteLine(string.Format("Process Name: {0} \t\t Process GUI Title:{1}",p.ProcessName, processTitle));
        }
    }
}
```