# Launch outlook new meeting from Java

Tags: java, outlook

Is it possible to launch outlook new meeting form from Java? (Not send the new meeting request, just launch the form).

I would also like to pass in the sent to email list.

I have been testing this:

```
Desktop desktop;
URI mailto = new URI("mailto:testmail@google.com");
desktop.mail(mailto);
```

However, this only launch outlook new mail, not new meeting.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

OS specific solution. I guess your making a Java app, even if its multi OS. i do not think it will be more than 4-5 OS? so need some OS specific code

1. First detect if outlook.exe is runnig, if not run it
2. then from java call a native API to bring that window to the foreground. See [get the titles of all open windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268302/get-the-titles-of-all-open-windows)
3. send keys to the app using java.awt.Robot to start a new meeting (ctrl-get the keys i dont have outlook i think CTRL+SHIFT+A per https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#calendar10)