# How can extract string matches using regular expression from a List?

Tags: c#, regex, list

I have a List contain some strings inside like this and other data.

```
  HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cda6c3f4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-5322ca90eeex]
  HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cadac3f4-8c87-4b12-8q3d-1qwe2ca90eec]
  HwndWrapper[App.exe;;c1b6a3s4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-2qw2ca90eeev]
```

My list:
            // Returns a list of WindowInformation objects with Handle, Caption, Class,
            // Parent, Children, Siblings and process information

```
 List<WindowInformation> windowListExtended = WindowList.GetAllWindowsExtendedInfo();
```

The regular expresion to match is:

```
  HwndWrapper\[App.exe;;.*?\]
```

Now for every match on the list. I need extract the string matched and run a process with every string extracted, Foreach or something like that.

Some help please.

Update:
Thanks Altaris for the help, just need convert List to string

```
        var message = string.Join(",", windowListExtended);
        string pattern = @"HwndWrapper\[LogiOverlay.exe;;.*?]";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message, pattern);
```

Comment: Your regex should be like :  HwndWrapper\[App\.exe;;(.*?)\]
Then the extracted string can be retrieved by Group 1

Comment: I could not find much information about WindowInformation object and how to work with it, may be this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268302/get-the-titles-of-all-open-windows

Comment: The window is non active, non standard window, with no name, only the class is available in relative easy way.    ;(
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still don't understand from where did you get this strings "HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cda6c3f4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-5322ca90eeex]"

Comment: I pickup form all window list.
Anyway, your solution work like a charm, is  very simple, just convert to string

    var message = string.Join(",", windowListExtended);
     string pattern = @"HwndWrapper\[LogiOverlay.exe;;.*?]";
     MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message, pattern);

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Final comment, check the update :)
Thanks a lot again!! work like charm now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to extract every match in a separate list to work with, there you go:

```
            var someList = new List<string>{"HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cda6c3f4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-5322ca90eeex]",
                                    "HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cadac3f4-8c87-4b12-8q3d-1qwe2ca90eec]",
                                    "HwndWrapper[App.exe;;c1b6a3s4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-2qw2ca90eeev]"};

            Regex FindHwndWrapper = new Regex(@"HwndWrapper\[App.exe;;(.*)\]");

            var matches = someList.Where(s => FindHwndWrapper.IsMatch(s)).ToList();

            foreach(var match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match);// Use values
            }
```

I used `System.Linq` function `Where()` to iterate through list

Use this Linq line if you want just the id parts, like "cda6c3f4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-5322ca90eeex"

```
var matches = someList.Select(s => FindHwndWrapper.Match(s).Groups[1]).ToList();
```

Comment: Apologize i update the info.
My list is List<WindowInformation>

Comment: More info is there.

Answer (score 1):

*I am unsure of what you want exactly, I think you want to extract these*

```
        List<string> windowListExtended = new List<string>();
        windowListExtended.Add("HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cda6c3f4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-5322ca90eeex]");
        windowListExtended.Add("HwndWrapper[App.exe;;cadac3f4-8c87-4b12-8q3d-1qwe2ca90eec]");
        windowListExtended.Add("HwndWrapper[App.exe;;c1b6a3s4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-2qw2ca90eeev]");

        var myRegex = new Regex(@"HwndWrapper\[App.exe;;.*?]");
        var resultList = files.Where(x => myRegex.IsMatch(x)).Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ";;","]" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]).ToList();

        //Now resultList contains => cda6c3f4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-5322ca90eeex, cadac3f4-8c87-4b12-8q3d-1qwe2ca90eec, c1b6a3s4-8c87-4b12-8f3d-2qw2ca90eeev
        foreach (var item in resultList)
        {
            //Do whatever you want
        }
```

Comment: Please apologize, take a tool again now, I update with more info.
List no is <string>  is  List<WindowInformation>

Comment: I still don't understand what the logic of your code is. I think you should be more crystal clear. @MrBi