# Reading a process name how it is displayed in Windows Task Manager in Golang

Tags: go, .net-core

I'm currently trying to read the name of a process in Go how it is represented in the windows task manager.

However, when I read it in Go it is displayed always as the executable. I'm trying to get it how it is named in the task manager.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process"
)

func main() {
    p, _ := process.Processes()
    for _, pr := range p {
        fmt.Println(pr.Name())
    }
}
```

This outputs all process names but none match how it is shown here:

[image]

I am trying to read the Spotify process name that is displayed with the song title.

Comment: XY Problem? Do you want the application title, or do you want the current song and artist name?

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get window title

Each time you open the "**Windows Task Manager**" it searches for [*.Net process.MainWindowTitle property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle), so you cant grep Windows title using **gopsutil** ... you have to use some *Go wrapper for the .NET Core Runtime* , not sure maybe [this one](https://github.com/matiasinsaurralde/go-dotnet) would be helpful ... [or even use C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268375/3033586) instead of Golang

### Get currently playing track on Spotify

Spotify has [awesome docs with API usage for such case](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track)
so you only need to generate auth token and convert next curl request to golang fetch function

```sh
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing?market=UA" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR TOKEN>>"
```

Comment: This lead me to the write answer, thank you!