# Minimize all instances of Notepad not working on Windows 11

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-11

I am working on C# code which minimize all open instances of Notepad. This code works fine on Windows 10, but when I run the same exe with administrator privilege, it minimize only one instance of Notepad (out of open 3..).

My code for this is as follows. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
class Program
{
    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool MinimizeWindow(System.IntPtr hwnd);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process thisProcess =
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes =
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in processes)
        {
            if (process == thisProcess) 
                continue;

            System.IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;

            if (handle == System.IntPtr.Zero) 
                continue;

            IntPtr s1 = process.MainWindowHandle;
            ShowWindowAsync(s1, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to minimize the classic Win32 notepad or the new Win11 WinUI Notepad?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but should "notepad" be "Notepad" ?

Comment: I *think* this relates to the way the tabbing/multi-doc is implemented, i.e. there may be a shared process with multiple window handles... in which case: this would get messy; running notepad 3 times locally: I have 3 windows and 1 process

Comment: Nobody said each window gets its own process. The new Notepad uses the same techniques Word, Excel and other applications used since the 2000s to handle multiple windows with a *single* application

Comment: @Ray Hi I am trying to minimize win11 Notepad. its works on window10 for all instances but on window11 its minimize only 1 instances but left all maximize. can you please provide me a solution for it. thanks

Comment: @Pankaj You've wrote that before, but there can be 2 versions of Notepad on Win11. The classic Win32 / Win10 one and the new Win11 one. If this code doesn't work on Win11, you may be using the new one which handles windows differently.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the thread and it works for me :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640787/16764520

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using HWND = System.IntPtr;

/// <summary>Contains functionality to get all the open windows.</summary>
public static class OpenWindowGetter
{
    /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
    /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
    public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
    {
        HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
        Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

        EnumWindows(delegate (HWND hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
            if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

            int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (length == 0) return true;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

            windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
            return true;

        }, 0);

        return windows;
    }

    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
}
class Program
{
    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool MinimizeWindow(System.IntPtr hwnd);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
        {
            IntPtr handle = window.Key;
            string title = window.Value;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", handle, title);
            if (title.Contains("- Notepad"))
            {
                ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```