# Recognize active window c#

Tags: c#, window, active-window

I was wondering if it was possible for c# to be able to identify an active window. Such as if Chrome or Firefox is the active window, the program would respond to a list of commands or cases specific to when that window is active.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029495/c-sharp-get-information-about-current-active-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to P/Invoke the [GetForegroundWindow Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the window the user is interacting with, and then use the other [Window Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get more information about the window.

Comment: Thank you. This should help quite a bit.